# Writing the following in latex

Tags: math-mode

In a wide variety of simple disease models, the rate of change in the number of
infected people can be written as

[image]

where

I is the number of infected people,Sis the number of susceptible people,

¹is the total number of people in the population,bis the transmission rate of
the disease, and mis the rate at which individuals leave the infected group.

Here IQ means the derivative of I with respect to time, a convention we will use
throughout the paper.

Equation (1) is applicable to a wide variety of one-group models. Following Castillo-Chavez et al. [3], we allow bto be a function of ¹, allowing
a variety of assumptions about mixing. Depending on the type of model, the
per-capita removal rate,m, may include the rate of ‘‘background’’ mortality or
disease-induced mortality, or transitions to immune, susceptible or quarantined compartments.][1]

Comment: -1: This really doesn't show any research effort.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I agree with @Werner that this doesn't really show any effort. If you really have no idea how to do that, maybe you should start learning LaTeX systematically, some ideas are in ["What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner). If you know how to do that but you have a specific problem, please explain what this specific problem is.

Comment: What is the question now? How to solve this SIR - like model?

Answer (score 4):

What is the problem with typesetting this? Please clarify your question! Where are you having problems? And please use an MWE like the following:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

In a wide variety of simple disease models, the rate of change in the number of
infected people can be written as
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
\dot{I}=\beta\frac{SI}{T}-mI=\biggl(\beta\frac{S}{T}-m\biggr)I,
\end{equation}
where $I$ is the number of infected people, $S$ is the number of susceptible people,
$T$ is the total number of people in the population, $\beta$ is the transmission rate
of the disease, and $m$ is the rate at which individuals leave the infected group.
Here $\dot{I}$ means the derivative of $I$ with respect to time, a convention we will
use throughout the paper. Equation \eqref{eq:1} is applicable to a wide variety of
one-group models. Following Ca\-stillo-Chavez et al.\ [3], we allow $b$ to be a
function of $T$, allowing a variety of assumptions about mixing. Depending on the type
of model, the per-capi\-ta removal rate, $m$, may include the rate of
\enquote{background} mortality or disease-induced mortality, or transitions to immune,
susceptible or quarantined compartments.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (not really related to the question) I would prefer `et al.~[3]` ;)